# SQL database join

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I want to sort books written by English author in `DESC` order of publication year. I've googled up inner join but I cannot convert string to int so it doesn't work. Any ideas please?

```
CREATE DATABASE [Books Database]

    CREATE TABLE [Books]
    (
    [id] [int] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    [book name] [NVARCHAR] (75),
    [year published] [int],
    [book prize won] [NVARCHAR] (75),
    )



    INSERT INTO [Books] ([book name], [year published], [book prize won])
    VALUES('Amsterdam',1998, 'Booker prize')

    INSERT INTO [Books]
    VALUES('The God of Small Things',1997, 'Booker prize')

    INSERT INTO [Books]
    VALUES('The Cost of Living',1999, NULL)

    INSERT INTO [Books]
    VALUES('Last Orders',1996, 'Booker prize')

    INSERT INTO [Books]
    VALUES('The Sweetshop Owner',1997,NULL)

    INSERT INTO [Books]
    VALUES('How Late it Was, How Late',1994 , 'Booker prize')

    INSERT INTO [Books]
    VALUES('Spirit Level',1996, 'Whitbread Poetry and the Whitbread Book prizes')

    INSERT INTO [Books]
    VALUES('Behind the Scenes at the Museum',1995  , 'Whitbread Book prize')

    INSERT INTO [Books]
    VALUES('Emotionally Weird',2000, NULL)

    INSERT INTO [Books]
    VALUES('Human Croquet',1998, NULL)

    INSERT INTO [Books]
    VALUES('Felicia''s Journey' ,1994, 'Whitbread Novel and the Whitbread Book prizes')

    INSERT INTO [Books]
    VALUES('Every Man for Himself',1996, 'Whitbread Novel prize')

    INSERT INTO [Books]
    VALUES('Midnight''s Children',1980, 'Booker prize')

    INSERT INTO [Books]
    VALUES('The Satanic Verses',1988, 'Whitbread Novel prize')

    INSERT INTO [Books]
    VALUES('The Moor''s Last Sigh',1995 , 'Whitbread Novel prize')


    INSERT INTO [Books]
    VALUES('Larry''s Party',1998, 'Orange prize')


    INSERT INTO [Books]
    VALUES('Fugitive Pieces',1997 , 'Orange and the Guardian Fiction prizes')


    INSERT INTO [Books]
    VALUES('Reading in the Dark' ,1996 , 'Guardian Fiction prize')


    INSERT INTO [Books]
    VALUES('Debatable Land',1994, 'Guardian Fiction prize')


    CREATE TABLE [Authors]
    (
    [id] [int] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    [author name] [NVARCHAR] (75),
    [author surname] [NVARCHAR] (75),
    [nationality] [NVARCHAR] (75),
    [yob] [int]
    )


    INSERT INTO [Authors] ([author name], [author surname],[nationality], [yob])
    VALUES('Ian', 'McEwan', 'English', 1948)

    INSERT INTO [Authors]
    VALUES('Arundhati','Roy', 'Indian', 1961)

    INSERT INTO [Authors]
    VALUES('Graham','Swift', 'English', 1949)

    INSERT INTO [Authors]
    VALUES('James','Kelman', 'Scottish', 1946)

    INSERT INTO [Authors]
    VALUES('Seamus','Heaney', 'Irish', 1939)

    INSERT INTO [Authors]
    VALUES('Kate','Atkinson', 'English', 1951)

    INSERT INTO [Authors]
    VALUES('William','Trevor','Irish', 1928)

    INSERT INTO [Authors]
    VALUES('Beryl','Bainbridge','English', 1936)

    INSERT INTO [Authors]
    VALUES('Salman','Rushdie','Indian', 1947)

    INSERT INTO [Authors]
    VALUES('Carol','Shields','American', 1950)

    INSERT INTO [Authors]
    VALUES('Anne','Michaels','Canadian', 1955)

    INSERT INTO [Authors]
    VALUES('Seamus','Deane','Irish', 1940)

    INSERT INTO [Authors]
    VALUES('Candia','McWilliam','Scottish', 1955)



    /* 1) List name and surname of all authors in alphabetical order. */
    SELECT TOP 1000 [id]
          ,[author name]
          ,[author surname]
          ,[nationality]
          ,[yob]
      FROM [Books Database].[dbo].[Authors]
      ORDER BY [author name],[author surname] ASC



        /* 2) List title of all books written by English authors in descending order of publication year. */


    SELECT TOP 1000
           [author name]
          ,[author surname]
          ,[nationality]
          ,[yob]
      FROM [Books Database].[dbo].[Authors]
      INNER JOIN [Books Database].[dbo].[Books]
      ON [Books Database].[dbo].[Authors].[nationality] = [Books Database].[dbo].[Books].[year published]
      ORDER BY [year published] DESC
```

Comment: `so it doesn't work` ... this doesn't make it any easier for us to help you.  Also, there doesn't appear to be a way to relate the `Book` and `Author` tables.  The join you are doing doesn't make sense and I don't see anything that would.

Comment: Tagged `sql-server` but you mention `mysql` in your question. Please clarify.

Comment: Your join goes from an authors nationality to a books publish year - does this sound like a sensible join to you?

Comment: How to Join the two tables?. The only possibility would be year column.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues in the following `JOIN` query:

```
INNER JOIN [Books Database].[dbo].[Books]
ON [Books Database].[dbo].[Authors].[nationality] = [Books Database].[dbo].[Books].[year published]
```

**Issue 1:**

Here `[nationality]` is the `VARCHAR(75)` and `[year published]` is `INT`. Matching the different datatype will cause the conversion issue.

The above condition can be modify to:

```
FROM [Books Database].[dbo].[Authors] AU
INNER JOIN [Books Database].[dbo].[Books] BO ON AU.[yob] = BO.[year published]
```

it mean matching the year values from the both tables and their datatype is `INT`

**Issue 2:**

Hope those also won't return any data in your case, because in `Authors` table `yob` is range from year  1928 to 1961 and in `Books` it range from year 1980 to 2000.

I added `AU`, `BO` are the table alias name for the better readability.

Comment: Yep, it does not return anything, how should i fix it ?

Comment: @TudorIoanVelcescu: Add valid matching year in both the tables. Else using [`LEFT JOIN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894(v=office.12).aspx), you can get the result from the first table if it doesn't have any match.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need some way to link a book to its author(s). As a book can have many authors, and an author can have many books, this will typically be modelled as a [Many-to-many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) (Somewhat unsurprisingly, the example wiki uses for M2M relationships are books-Authors)

You need to add another table, called something along the lines of "BookAuthors" which contains a foreign key to book `id` and a foreign key to author `id`.

Once you have that you join Books to BookAuthors and BookAuthors to Authors, filter by only authors who are English and put the results in reverse publication year order

It will be along the lines of

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 b.[book name],
 b.[year published]
FROM Books b
INNER JOIN BookAuthors ba ON b.id = ba.bookId
INNER JOIN Authors a ON ba.authorId = a.Id
WHERE a.nationality = 'English'
ORDER BY  b.[year published] DESC
```

Comment: Can you please explain me how to create the foreign key to book ID ?

Comment: @TudorIoanVelcescu in SqlServer (tagged) or MySql (question text)

Comment: Foreign key in MySql

Comment: @TudorIoanVelcescu - [they tend to hide that information in the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)